# Error "unknown function set_config" connecting to Postgres database server using pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin-4

I get the following error while trying to connect to Postgres server 9.1.4. What am I missing? I am using pgAdmin 4 version 5.5

Thnaks[image]

Comment: I'm going to start with the fact that 9.1 is ~5 years past EOL. Now `set_config()` is available in 9.1, but I'm guessing there is a context issue that is keeping `pgAdmin` from using it. I would look at the Postgres log to see if you can get more information.

Answer (score 1):

From their [front page](https://www.pgadmin.org/)

> pgAdmin may be used on Linux, Unix, macOS and Windows to manage PostgreSQL and EDB Advanced Server **9.5** and above.

9.1.4 is much older than that.

Comment: Thank you. Any recommendation on clients (GUI)  to query 9.1.4?